# How to pull record for this month and last month in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to pull all records from this month and last month and convert it into percentage

@posts.all(this month).convert_to_%
and
@posts.all(last month).covert_to_%

Comment: Check the groupdate gem  https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Comment: Different db's let you do this in slightly different ways.  For instance with postgres you can do something like `Model.where("MONTH(date_column) = ? and Year(date_column) = ?", (DateTime.now -1.month).month, (DateTime.now -1.month).year)

Answer (score 0):

you do this from the database, but if you just want something that works, write a foreach statement that cycles through each record, skipping the record if the date falls outside of your criteria.

for instance here is an example of a foreach loop I use against a csv file comparing a salesmans name with a projects status and date.

```
def pending_sales(initials, salesperson)
      my_status = 'Pending'
      pending = 0
      count = 0
      CSV.foreach(path, :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8') do |row|
        salesman = row[1]
        project_manager = row[0]
        project_name = row[2]
        project_city = row[3]
        customer = row[4]
        status = row[6]
        bid_date = Date.strptime(row[7], '%m/%d/%Y')
        amount = row[8].tr(',', '').to_i
        next if salesman != initials || status != my_status || bid_date < fiscal_start
        dollar_amount = '$' + amount.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse
        pending = pending + amount
        count = count + 1
      end
      @pending_count = count.to_s
      @pending_amount = "$" + pending.to_s.reverse.gsub(/...(?=.)/,'\&,').reverse
    end
```